# Data's strength in "Star Trek: Insurrection"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data, star-trek-insurrection

When Artim fell and Data picked him up he looked like he was struggling carrying him. Afterwards, Data picked up a large boulder with no problem (like it wasn't heavy).

**Why was Artim heavier to carry than the boulder?**

Comment: Maybe the boy was made out of extremely dense matter.

Comment: Not familiar with the clip, but is it possible he appeared to be struggling because he was attempting not to exacerbate the boy's injuries with his immense strength?

Answer (score 10):

The very short answer is that in-universe, Data had no (evident) problems with Artim's weight. Picard passed him over and Data carried him a short way and then put him down. Since we know that Data can effortlessly carry a boy that size, any *imagined* exertion is simply down to your own incorrect perception.

> Picard reaches out for her... just as the whole thing comes down on
>   both of them... Picard throws Artim out of the cave just in front of
>   the collapse into the arms of...
>
> DATA
>
> who pulls him safely away from the collapse...
>
> <sub><sup>[Insurrection: Screenplay](http://movies.trekcore.com/insurrection/script.txt)</sup></sub>

and

> Abruptly, the boy stumbled through the opening, and Data’s strong arms caught Artim’s thin ones.
>   **With astonishing ease, the android pulled the boy away from the danger.**
>   At the sight of Data’s steady, placid expression, Artim felt a surge of relief-, that relief vanished at once when the boy turned to see the devastation he had left behind.
>
> <sub><sup>[Insurrection: Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

Out-of-universe, this is a perfect example of ***[Bellisario's Maxim](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim)***;

> "Don't examine this too closely"

Although the character of Data has superhuman strength, what you're *actually* looking at in this scene is actor Brent Spiner (a relatively slight man who's just turned 50) carrying a ten year old boy weighing approximately 30-35 kilos. In the next scene he's pretending to lift heavy boulders which are in fact polystyrene balls sprayed grey by a guy named [Clete](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0149151/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr60).

Comment: Please provide the evidence that Clete is actually the guy that painted those boulders.   (I would assume it was a joke, but you know things probably no one should know.)

Comment: @ThePopMachine - He's the film's "production foreman" In reality it could literally have been any of the film's set dressers; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120844/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast but Clete is the one with the funniest name

Comment: That's what I expected, but I'm a little disappointed.

Comment: *** Warning*** TV-Tropes link!